# How to get first top values of a column, then perform where conditions to reduce rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT TOP 25 customer
FROM tt
WHERE DocNum LIKE '%something%' AND U_NAME NOT LIKE '%something%'
GROUP BY customer
ORDER BY MIN(DocNum) DESC
```

Let's say I have the query above but obviously it returns the top 25 row of

```
SELECT customer 
FROM tt 
WHERE DocNum LIKE '%something%' 
  AND U_NAME NOT LIKE '%something%' 
GROUP BY customer 
ORDER BY MIN(DocNum) DESC
```

How can I get the

```
WHERE DocNum LIKE '%something%' 
  AND U_NAME NOT LIKE '%something%' 
GROUP BY customer 
ORDER BY MIN(DocNum) DESC
```

of the top 25 rows of customer?

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying you want to determine the 25 customers with the least docnums regardless of docnum and u_name first, and for these customers get all rows that match `DocNum LIKE '%something%' AND U_NAME NOT LIKE '%something%'`?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Is this SQL Server? Please tag your request with your DBMS.

Comment: Can two customers have the same docnum? If so, there may be customer 25 and 26 that share the same minimum docnum. Would you then want to select 26 customers? Or only 24? Or 25, where the 25th is arbitrarily chosen from the two tying ones?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results.

Comment: they can't have the same docnum @ThorstenKettner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause is evaluating before the `TOP` and `ORDER BY`. If you want to first get the `TOP 25` records order by `MIN(DocNum) DESC` then you need to perform this operation first. This can be achieved using sub-query like the following:

```
SELECT customer
FROM tt 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT TOP 25 customer
    FROM tt
    GROUP BY customer
    ORDER BY MIN(DocNum) DESC
) ds
    ON tt.customer = ds.customer
WHERE tt.DocNum LIKE '%something%' 
    AND tt.U_NAME NOT LIKE '%something%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the top 25 customers (which are the 25 with the least docnums) first. For these customers you want to select all rows that match certain docnum and u_name patterns:

```
WITH top25 AS
(
  SELECT TOP 25 customer
  FROM tt
  GROUP BY customer
  ORDER BY MIN(docnum) DESC
)
SELECT *
FROM tt
WHERE docnum LIKE '%something%' AND u_name NOT LIKE '%something%'
AND customer IN (SELECT customer FROM top25)
ORDER BY customer, docnum;
```